# Get direct path of database.mdf from project folder - file moved

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to get the direct path of my local database.

I put the database inside my main project folder:

[image]

Then I used this code to get the path:

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\database\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
```

Everything is OK now.

So why is the database copied into the `\bin\Debug` folder?

[image]

Then if I open the source code and run the project and try to save data or find data that I saved before from the application in `\bin\Debug` I don't find it? Why?

What I mean

1. If I run the project from `\bin\Debug` its will save
2. If I run the project from project1 folder from (.sln) and try to show the data table I don't find may saved data.
3. The opposite is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it works. You add a data file to your project and it is a source file. You build your schema in that file and you also add any default data to that file. You don't use that file for testing and debugging though. How would it make sense to pollute that file with test data and then you've got no clean database to deploy with your application when you release it?

When you build, that source file gets copied to the output folder. If you build a Debug version, the data file gets copied to the Debug folder and that's where you mess it up with your test data. When your application is ready to deploy, you switch to a Release build and a nice clean copy of your source database is created in the Release folder.

By default, the `Copy to Output Directory` property of that source file is set to `Copy Always`. That means that any time you run your project and there are changes to any source file, a new copy will overwrite the one already in the Debug folder and any changes you made last time you debugged will be lost. If you change that property to `Copy if Newer`, a new copy will only be made if you change source data file. That allows you to keep changes between debugging runs. To force a refresh, just do a Clean or delete the copy manually.